# Visa application - what working status can be used for a freelancer?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, freelance

I'm applying for a UK visa, and one of question is about my current working status. I'm working as a freelancer (mainly for one company, but I'm not employed). What option should I use?

```
Employed Full Time
Employed Part Time
Retired
Self Employed
Student (Non Working)
Student (Working)
Supported by Spouse/Partner/Other
Unemployed
Voluntary / Unpaid Worker
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be `Self Employed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freelancer is usually self-employed, but please check [this question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2550/working-self-employed-in-england/) for more details on that.

Comment: The visa application form still requires to fill in "The Name of Company/Organisation/Employer", "Job Description / Title / Rank", address when I choose "Self-employed". What should I fill in as a self-employed worker?

Comment: I believe "freelancer" should suffice. :-)